# MongoDB Projecting specific values from objects in nested arrays according to filtering rules

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation, projection

I am pretty new to MongoDB, using it first time on a large-scale app. We have a complicated nested structure representing an object with multiple documents associated with it, and various people associated with each of those documents. For GUI building purposes, I need to extract and concat some information from the document hierarchy and "promote" it to a top-level, creating a simple flat structure. If there are multiple results for each nested "subquery", I am interested only in the first one.

I have tried to achieve this with the aggregation builder. Still, each time I ended up with over a hundred lines of endless unwind, addfield, project and it became too long and complicated (and also probably not very fast) to be viable. There has to be a simpler solution. Let me provide an example structure (I have omitted most fields, leaving just the essential ones for brevity):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "number": "ABC-123456",
    "status": "new",
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "name": "invoice",
            "people": [
                {
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "last_name": "Doe",
                    "active": false
                },
                {
                    "first_name": "Jane",
                    "last_name": "Smith",
                    "active": true
                },
                {
                    "first_name": "Fred",
                    "last_name": "Bloggs",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "name": "unimportant_document",
            "people": [
                {
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "last_name": "Doe",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "name": "order",
            "people": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Fred",
                    "last_name": "Bloggs",
                    "active": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I would like to get a result similar to this:

```
{
    "_id": "XXX",
    "number": "ABC-123456",
    "status": "new",
    "invoice_person_full_name": "Jane Smith",
    "order_person_full_name": "Fred Bloggs"
}
```

Basically, I need to concat "first_name" and "last_name" from the first person with "active": true in an array of people in a document of a certain name ("invoice" for "invoice_person_full_name" and "order" for "order_person_full_name").

I don't care about duplicates, so if there are multiple documents with the name "invoice" for example, I want to retrieve only the first invoice and the first active person for this invoice.

As I said, I have tried doing this with an aggregation builder, using project with the filter to filter the items array to only "invoice" names, then unwinding, projecting again filtering people, projecting again to get the first one, unwinding, adding fields, writing JS function to concat the name (in reality there are degrees, middle names, etc. that need to be separated with spaces and might be null, so `$concat` is not enough) and finally returning. This takes 40+ lines of code and works only for a single item name, so I need to combine this multiple times to get the result for all names I need. Which probably means I'm not approaching the problem in the right way.

I hope I made the question clear enough, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set`

   1.1. `invoice_persons` - Create field by getting the first document from `items` array which its `name` is "invoice".

   1.2. `order_persons` - Create field by getting the first document from `items` array which its `name` is "order".
2. `$set`

   2.1. `invoice_person_full_name` - First filter the document from `invoice_persons.people` which its `active` is `true`. Next with `$map` to perform string concatenation for full name. And lastly, get the first document.

   2.2. `order_person_full_name` - First filter the document from `order_persons.people` which its `active` is `true`. Next with `$map` to perform string concatenation for full name. And lastly, get the first document.
3. `$unset` - Remove fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "invoice_persons": {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$items",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.name",
                "invoice"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "order_persons": {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$items",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.name",
                "order"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "invoice_person_full_name": {
        $first: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$invoice_persons.people",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.active",
                    true
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            in: {
              "$concat": [
                "$$this.first_name",
                " ",
                "$$this.last_name"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "order_person_full_name": {
        $first: {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$order_persons.people",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.active",
                    true
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            in: {
              "$concat": [
                "$$this.first_name",
                " ",
                "$$this.last_name"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "invoice_persons",
      "order_persons",
      "items"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xl4AaX4zlap)

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick response, I tried it on the actual data and it works flawlessly.